# R calling string for lookup in a function

Tags: r, string

I'm trying to call a column name for the e1071 svm function. 
The working code looks like:

```
model = svm(Air_Flow~., data = trainset)
```

But in an effort to make it more automated I changed it to:

```
coi=44
model = svm(colnames(data)[coi]~., data = trainset)
```

where

This didn't work due (I think) to the quote marks, so I tried:

- get(colnames(data)[coi])
- cat(...)
- print(...,quote = F)
- as.name(...)
- parse(...)

Only get() sort of worked, but then when I tried to predict other values using model it didn't. Any suggestions on what may get this working?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Formulas are not strings that you can just "paste" variables into. Nor are variable names the same as strings. You need to be careful about how you build expressions to make sure you are using the correct type. Formulas are really un-evaluated calls that hold names/symbols as parameters.

You might consider using `bquote()` to build your formula expression, and be sure to convert the character version of the variable name to a proper variable name with `as.name()`

```
coi=44
model = svm(bquote(.(as.name(colnames(data)[coi])~.), data = trainset)
```

Yes, this is a bit ugly. That's why often functions that allow formulas also have an alternative interface that's easier to program against. `svm()` also allows you to pass in an `x` and `y` parameter for the response and predictors. You might do

```
model = svm(trainset[,col], trainset[,-col])
```

which is nicer because you can subset columns from your dataset with both string and numeric indexes